# MYSQL SUM of a row looking for 2 different values from another column

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL Query i need to do, it basically looks for 2 values in a column called item_code.
The values are "FWDBAL" and "INVLATECHARGE", i need it to calculate the sum of item_price of 2 columns with the values above.

```
Select sum(item_price) overdueBal from invoice_items where invoiceid='9' AND item_code='CADB-FWDBAL' AND item_code='CADB-INVLATECHARGE';
```

That is returning NULL from the Workbench, and i have no idea how to accomplish this. Is there a way that you can look for 2 values in one column and get the sum of another column from the 2 values i need?

Comment: `AND item_code='CADB-FWDBAL' AND item_code='CADB-INVLATECHARGE';` should be `AND (item_code='CADB-FWDBAL' OR item_code='CADB-INVLATECHARGE)';`

Answer (score 1):

No single record can match both of those item_codes at the same time. Think logically, it is day OR it is night. It can't be day AND night. So you need to say one or the other in parens or u can just use an IN which is a little nicer.

```
Select sum(item_price) overdueBal 
from invoice_items 
where invoiceid='9' 
AND item_code IN ( 'CADB-FWDBAL', 'CADB-INVLATECHARGE' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, turns out to look for columns with these values i needed to the OR keyword instead of AND.. Rookie Error on my part as im fairly new to SQL.